# IOS 17.0 Crash Webview based app when open any <select> </select>

Tags: ios

All seems correct on the app just when we try to open a   app crash.

Anybody notice something similar on their apps or know what can we do so far to solved?

Thanks you before hand.

Just trying to fix app crashing when select open

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no more info.. its what happening to my apps too... it just crashes on selecting native html dropdown..

Comment: the community here is shit.. posting without doing any research on the issue by thenselves.